# Code 403 : "The request is missing a valid API key." PERMISSION_DENIED Service Account Key Google Cloud Vision PHP

Tags: php, codeigniter, google-api, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-vision

I want to implement the Google Cloud Vision with ImageAnnotator using a service key. What i have try is like below :

**Error :**

> Message: {
>         "error": {
>           "code": 403,
>           "message": "The request is missing a valid API key.",
>           "status": "PERMISSION_DENIED"
>         }
>       }

**When try this code :**

```
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

use Google\Cloud\Vision\VisionClient;

class Admin_center extends CI_Controller {
    function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();

        include APPPATH . 'third_party/vendor/autoload.php';
    }

    public function index() {
        $this->load->view('index');
    }

    function upload_ocr_image() {               
        $img_data = $this->upload->data();                                          

        $vision = new VisionClient(['keyfile' => json_decode(file_get_contents(base_url().'assets/google_cloud_vision/credentials.json'), true)]);

        $imageRes = fopen($img_data['full_path'], 'r');
        $image = $vision->image($imageRes,['Text_Detection']);
        $result = $vision->annotate($image);

        print_r($result);
    }
}
```

I used a **service account** key.

Why i got error : 403 Permissin Denied and Missing a valid API Key ?

**Edited :**

I have follow this youtube tutorial :

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=K-tpjOT7k-o

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PqAXE67fwu8&t=2s

Thank You

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally IT WORKED after 5 hours struggle to find the problem.

Actually the code i have posted above it is worked.
I just mistype the Array name.

So this line :

```
$vision = new VisionClient(['keyfile' => json_decode(file_get_contents(base_url().'assets/google_cloud_vision/credentials.json'), true)])
```

the 'keyfile' should be 'keyFile' with 'F' is an uppercase.

That's all.

Thank you for all you helps..

Answer (score 0):

Simply replace `'credentials.json'` with the path to the actual file... which it cannot find alike that.

Comment: I already replace the actual file path to the file_get_contents. But still has same error.. See my edit

Comment: @DennisLiu does `die(file_get_contents(base_url().'assets/google_cloud_vision/credentials.json'))` output the JSON and are you certain that these credentials have been granted access to the Cloud Vision API (double-check that in the console)?

Comment: i have try to echo the file_get_contents and i print the json file. So i didn't put a wrong link. But to make sure have been granted access to the cloud Vision API how to check it ?

Comment: also i have try to recreate the service account and i set the role to project->owner. And in the user grant permission i set the gmail. But still same error.

Comment: with service-accounts this works slightly different: `$config = ['keyFilePath' => $serviceAccountPath, 'projectId' => $projectId];` [source](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/production#auth-cloud-implicit-php).

Comment: if i use 'keyFilePath' than the error return 'file does not exist' so i change again use a 'keyfile' with project-id. But still same error. Is this something about because i didn't have a billing in there ? because i want to try first and if it worked than i will put a billing for live later. If free to try which service account should i use ?

Comment: @DennisLiu you can't just enter whatever you want there. see the documentation.

Comment: It may sound like a dumb question but do you actually have an API Key which allows access to Cloud Vision? The error message is pretty self explanatory. You either fail to provide the API key or the one you're using is invalid

Comment: @MartinZeitler but i follow the documentation using $config = ['keyFilePath' => $serviceAccountPath, 'projectId' => $projectId]; and the result is got error File Does Exist.  Looks like file path is not detected properly. But when i open the file path. The file is there.

Comment: @JavierLarroulet Yes i have create a service account keys. And i set the role to project->owner. I have also download the and create key and get the blablabal.json file which contain information about the private_key, project-id and soon. Then i put it into the project directory.

Comment: Did you guys success try this google cloud vision with service account keys ? If yes. But did you guys did ? Could you show me the step to see if i did it right. I cannot figure out what is missing in here